# I want a more efficient answer with these methods only

Tags: python, string, methods

I have been self teaching myself python for the past 2 weeks. Today, I came across a problem and I have a very annoying solution to it(I feel bad for whoever has to read it). So firstly, I will introduce the problem and my solution to it.

Problem:Complete the getHost() function, which takes a single string argument representing a URL and returns a string that cor-
responds to the next-to-last section of the hostname. For example, given the URL "http://www.example.com/", the function

would return the string "example". Given the URL "ftp://this.is.a.long.name.net/path/to/some/file.php", the function would
return the string "name". While the path and filename sections of the URL are optional, you may assume that the full
hostname is always followed by a single forward slash ("/").

My solution:

```
def getHost(x):
    newstring = ""
    listofx = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        listofx.append(x[i])
    for j in range(2):
        a = listofx.index("/")
        listofx.reverse()
        for k in range(a+1):
            listofx.pop()
        listofx.reverse()
    b = listofx.index("/")
    for g in range(len(listofx)-b):
        listofx.pop()
    for t in range(listofx.count(".")-1):
        for o in range(listofx.index(".")+1):
            listofx.reverse()
            listofx.pop()
            listofx.reverse()
    for f in range(len(listofx)-listofx.index(".")):
        listofx.pop()
    for h in range(len(listofx)):
        newstring = newstring + listofx[h]
    print (newstring)
```

I HATE my solution because look at how many for loops I used. I felt like I had no choice since strings are immutable. I would appreciate someone can showing me a solution using while loops and the find()/rfind() methods. I do not want to keep converting strings to lists to solve these type of problems.

Comment: Well written question

Comment: not answering your question, but `urlparse` will help to get rid of the majority of your code and then you can get the hostname and split it on '.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` and `rfind`:

```
def getHost(x):
    index1 = x.find('//')
    index2 = x.find('/', index1+2)
    index3 = x.rfind('.',index1+2, index2)
    return(x[:index3].split('.')[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is better (pythonic) way

```
def extract(data):
    print(data.split('/')[2].split('.')[-2])

extract("http://www.example.com/")
extract("ftp://this.is.a.long.name.net/path/to/some/file.php")
```

Output (obviously)

```
example
name
```

Comment: I am asking for a solution that incorporates while loops and the methods find() and rfind().

Comment: I would like to note, great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your URL always has the double forward slash you could use something like the following;

```
url = "http://www.example.com/"

url = url.split("/")
url = url[2].split(".")
getHost = url[-2]

print(getHost)
```

Comment: What about `file:/abc.def/ghi` or `wwe.example.com`?

Comment: @khachik `http://wwe.example.com` would work, however the file path would not as it does not start with a double forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a simpler version that doesn't need `rfind`:

```
def getHost(x):
    index1 = x.find('//')
    index2 = x.find('/', index1+2)
    return(x[:index2].split('.')[-2])



print(getHost("ftp://this.is.a.long.name.net/path/to/some/file.php"))
print(getHost("http://www.example.com/"))
```